# nektos/act docker containers. How to mount a volume?

Tags: docker, go, github-actions

###### How can I get `act` to create containers with a defined volume mounted?

I have created a local instance of a docker runner. I'm looking to optimise running of https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-miniconda

- have created a docker image and a docker repository
- have switched to using `conda-lock` to remove need to resolve `environment.yaml`
- now the final step so that Conda package downloads can be shared across containers created by **act** with a volume mount in the container.  Equivalent of:

```
docker run -it -v /home/vagrant/miniconda/pkgs/:/root/miniconda3/pkgs localhost:5000/my-act /bin/bash
```

Have tried patching **docker_run.go**

```
func (cr *containerReference) Create(capAdd []string, capDrop []string) common.Executor {
    cr.input.Mounts["/root/miniconda3/pkgs"] = "/home/vagrant/miniconda/pkgs"
    return common.
        NewInfoExecutor("%sdocker create image=%s platform=%s entrypoint=%+q cmd=%+q", logPrefix, cr.input.Image, cr.input.Platform, cr.input.Entrypoint, cr.input.Cmd).
        Then(
            common.NewPipelineExecutor(
                cr.connect(),
                cr.find(),
                cr.create(capAdd, capDrop),
            ).IfNot(common.Dryrun),
        )
}
```

`.actrc`

```
-P ubuntu-latest=localhost:5000/my-act
```

Script to create local docker repository

```
actimg="localhost:5000/my-act"
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker build --no-cache -t act-custom:v1 .
docker tag act-custom:v1 $actimg
docker push $actimg
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
ARG CONDA=/root/miniconda
ENV CONDA=$CONDA
ENV INSTALL_MINICONDA=$CONDA
ARG NODE=/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.18.1/x64/bin/node
ENV RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE=/opt/hostedtoolcache
ENV RUNNER_TEMP=/tmp
RUN dl=$( curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/conda-incubator/setup-miniconda/releases/latest | jq -r '.zipball_url' ) \
    && wget -q -O dl2.zip $dl \
    && unzip -q dl2.zip -d dl2 \
    && env INPUT_ARCHITECTURE=x64 \
        INPUT_AUTO-ACTIVATE-BASE=true \
        INPUT_AUTO-UPDATE-CONDA=false \
        INPUT_CLEAN-PATCHED-ENVIRONMENT-FILE=true \
        INPUT_MINIFORGE-VARIANT=mambaforge \
        INPUT_MINIFORGE-VERSION=latest \
        INPUT_REMOVE-PROFILES=false \
        INPUT_RUN-POST=true \
        INPUT_USE-MAMBA=true \
        ${NODE} $( find dl2/ -wholename "*/dist/setup/index.js" ) \
    && source ${CONDA}3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh \
    && conda config --set default_threads 4 \
    && ${NODE} $( find dl2/ -wholename "*/dist/delete/index.js" ) \
    && mamba install conda-lock \
    && mamba clean --all \
    && rm -r /opt/hostedtoolcache/mambaforge/ \
    && rm -rf * \
    && mv /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin-old \
    && ln -s ${CONDA}3/bin /usr/local/bin
ENV CONDA=${CONDA}3
ENV PATH=${CONDA}/bin:${PATH}
VOLUME /root/miniconda3/pkgs
COPY /home/vagrant/geopandas/ci/lock /root/lock
CMD [ "/usr/bin/tail -f /dev/null" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
--container-options "-v ~/myproj:/home/user/projects/myproj/"
https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1548

Also, you can try --bind but it changes all the act container relative path resolution.